# how to print more readable print statement in awk

Tags: awk

Suppose the following `awk` code:

```
awk -v one="one" -v two="two" -v three="three" '{ printf "hello %s, sup %s? Bye %s", one, two, three }'
```

There's a `printf` in Python called `formatted string` which is used like this:

```
one = "one"
two = "two"
three = "three"
print(f'hello {one}, sup {two}? Bye {three}.')
```

I'm looking something like similar to this in `awk`. I didn't find such thing till now in my google results.

**Update 1**

I also tried this, but looking for another (maybe better if exists):

```
awk -v one="one" -v two="two" -v three="three" '{ print "hello", one, "sup", two, "? Bye", three, "." }'
```

Comment: So you want to be able to put variable names in awk print statements?

Comment: @FlyingTeller yes.

Comment: do you need `printf`? Your example could be achieved with `awk -v one="one" -v two="two" -v three="three" '{ print "hello "one", sup "two"? Bye "three}'`

Comment: @FlyingTeller Please see my comment in the answer of RavinderSingh13.

Comment: In awk: `printf "Hello %s sup %s bye %s" , one, two, three`.

Comment: Setting your variables to the same value as their name in your example is a bad choice as then when testing we can't tell if a potential solution is printing the variable's name or it's contents. You should use `awk -v one='this & that' -v two='are' -v three='something'` or similar to also test a solution works if spaces are included and no-ones trying to just do a `sub()` (which would fail given the `&` backreference).

Answer (score 3):

With your shown attempts please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v one="one" -v two="two" -v three="three" '
BEGIN{
  print "hello " one ", sup " two ", bye " three
}
'
```

I have used `BEGIN` section above where you need not to pass Input_file, in case you want to read an Input_file also you could remove it and pass Input_file at the last of above code.

Comment: Thanks but when the line is long, it's hard to debug if I missed any quotation or not. I forgot to mention I tried this but I don't prefer this. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Saeed, yes that's there. But you are comparing python with awk, awk is a ever green language where python is mordern hot in market language. You could use good IDEs to make sure things are properly closed in here just in case.

Comment: @Saeed, I have added another answer with custom function, we could discuss there, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : you sure it's all that hot, considering Google themselves kinda abandoned `python` in favor of `go` once they lost control of the narrative. And the latest changes in `python` are super annoying - you couldn't print out any sizable integer without it screaming in your face about too many digits (if they did that as a band-aid solution to a `CVE`, then it's solving the wrong problem)

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto, sure, it was just a comment from my understanding, good that you added your point here 

Answer (score 3):

Awk is a tiny, simple language because the providers deliberately will not introduce language constructs to do something that's easy to do with other existing constructs. If you don't have that mindset then you end up with [language bloat](https://www.zoitz.com/archives/13). What you want to do is easily done with `print` or `printf` so no, there is no additional language construct in awk to also do it.

If you're concerned about:

```
print "hello "one", sup "two"? Bye "three"."
```

being hard to debug if you missed a `"` then write it as:

```
print "hello " \
      one      \
      ", sup " \
      two      \
      "? Bye " \
      three    \
      "."
```

or similar.

IMHO code to print multiple values in a formatted string is clearer and easier to maintain if you separate the format from the data though:

```
printf "hello %s, sup %s? Bye %s.\n", one, two, three
```

Having said that.... if you really wanted this functionality then you could create a function to provide it using GNU awk for `patsplit()`, `SYMTAB`, `FUNCTAB`, and `isarray()`:

```
awk -v one='this & that' -v two='are' -v three='something' '

    BEGIN{ print f("hello {one}, sup {two}? Bye {three}.") }
    
    function f(str,      nf,out,vars,seps,i,var,val) {
        nf = patsplit(str,vars,/\{[[:alnum:]_]+}/,seps)
        out = out seps[0]
        for ( i=1; i<=nf; i++ ) {
            var = substr(vars[i],2,length(vars[i])-2)
            if ( (var in SYMTAB) && !(var in FUNCTAB) && !isarray(SYMTAB[var]) ) {
                val = SYMTAB[var]
            }
            else {
                val = vars[i]
            }
            out = out val seps[i]
        }
        return out
    }

'
hello this & that, sup are? Bye something.
```

with the caveat that that'll only work for global scalar variables, not function-local ones (as `SYMTAB` only contains global variables), nor a value at an array index (as that doesn't have a name in `SYMTAB`), nor anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a Generic answer here, where I have created a custom function which accepts strings which we want to pass along with variables which we have passed to `awk` and by this we need not to care about `"` thing(with too many variables stuff).

```
awk -v one="one" -v two="two" -v three="three" '
  function generate_Strings(str, allVariables){
    num1=split(str, arr1,",")
    num2=split(allVariables, arr2,"@")
    if(num1!=num2){
       print "exiting from program, since number of strings passed are NOT equal to number of variables mentioned in this program."
       exit
    }
    for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){
       value=(value?value OFS:"") arr1[i]", "arr2[i]
    }
   print value
  }
BEGIN{
  OFS=" : "
  generate_Strings("hello,sup,Bye","one@two@three")
}'
```

Make sure to pass strings within `"...."` and they should be `,`comma separated and then pass variable names within `"..."` separated by `@` in above code.

For examples above will show following output:

```
hello, one : sup, two : Bye, three
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I'll check that a couple of hours late when I'm home.

Comment: That's just printing the `@`-separated strings in `"one@two@three"`, it has nothing to do with the variables of the same name or the contents of those variables. If you change `"one@two@three"` to `one"@"two"@"three` THEN it'll print the values of those variables but then `generate_Strings("hello,sup,Bye",one"@"two"@"three)` isn't in any way better than`printf "hello %s sup %s Bye %s",one,two,three`, in fact it's worse as you've lost the ability to format the output.

Comment: Try running it with `awk -v one='this & that' -v two='are' -v three='something' ...` or similar so you can see if the variable's values are being printed or not.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you sir for your comment I didn't check that, in case it doesn't work I can add a warning in answer then sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check this out:

```
awk -v one="one" -v two="two" -v three="three" 'BEGIN {
    message = sprintf("hello %s, sup %s? Bye %s", one, two, three);
    print message
}'
```

as you see,inside the `BEGIN` block, I have the `sprintf` function and it takes a format string and a list of values and returns a formatted string. in this case, I am formatting the message string using the values of `one`, `two`, and `three`!

output

```
hello one, sup two? Bye three
```

Answer (score 1):

> There's a printf in Python called formatted string(...)

What you have used is called f-string or if you wish to follow its' [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) *Literal String Interpolation*, I never seen `printf` name for them.

> I'm looking something like similar to this in awk

[The AWK programming language](https://archive.org/details/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7) contains example of **Form Letters**, this is done by calling `gsub` many times with suitably crafted 1st argument.

Comment: Yes you're right sir, there's no `printf` in Python, I meant the `f-string` which is `print(f'...')`. I didn't notice the typo/mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Like a variant:

```
$ awk '{print "hello", $1, "sup", $2"? Bye", $3"."}' <<< "one two three"
hello one sup two? Bye three.
```

Comment: That's a good one, but my real data contains a file with some columns, for example `$6`. Then do they conflict?